# PDF/A was validated correctly with preflight but online pdf-tools does not validate it

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdfa

Preflight (version 2.0.15) tool has validated correctly the generated pdf (was created with pdfbox version 2.0.15) file but online pdf-tools (e.x. https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx) does not validate it correctly. I am getting below error:

Compliance  pdfa-1b
Result  Document does not conform to PDF/A.
Details 
Validating file "file.pdf" for conformance level pdfa-1b

Anonymous RDF resources (rdf:Description without rdf:about attribute) are not allowed in XMP Metadata.

The appearance dictionary doesn't contain an entry.

The appearance dictionary doesn't contain an entry.

The appearance dictionary doesn't contain an entry.

The appearance dictionary doesn't contain an entry.

The appearance dictionary doesn't contain an entry.

The document does not conform to the requested standard.

The document contains annotations or form fields with ambigous or without appropriate appearances.

The document's meta data is either missing or inconsistent or corrupt.
The document does not conform to the PDF/A-1b standard.

Done.

In order to generate metadata I use below code:

```
private void addMetadata(PDDocument pdDocument,final String zzz,final String yyy) {

    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDDocumentInformation info = pdDocument.getDocumentInformation();
    info.setCreationDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    info.setModificationDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    info.setAuthor(metadataAuthor);
    info.setProducer(metadataProducer);
    info.setTitle(zzz + "_" + yyy);
    info.setKeywords("aaa");
    info.setCreator("aaa");
    info.setSubject("aaa");

    PDMarkInfo markInfo = new PDMarkInfo();
    markInfo.setMarked(true);
    catalog.setMarkInfo(markInfo);

    try {
        PDMetadata metadataStream = new PDMetadata(pdDocument);
        catalog.setMetadata( metadataStream );

        XMPMetadata xmp = new XMPMetadata();
        XMPSchemaPDFAId pdfaid = new XMPSchemaPDFAId(xmp);
        xmp.addSchema(pdfaid);
        pdfaid.setConformance("B");
        pdfaid.setPart(1);
        pdfaid.setAbout("");

        XMPSchemaDublinCore dcSchema = xmp.addDublinCoreSchema();
        dcSchema.setTitle( info.getTitle() );
        dcSchema.addCreator("aaa");
        dcSchema.setDescription( info.getSubject() );

        XMPSchemaPDF pdfSchema = xmp.addPDFSchema();
        pdfSchema.setKeywords( info.getKeywords() );
        pdfSchema.setProducer( info.getProducer() );

        XMPSchemaBasic basicSchema = xmp.addBasicSchema();
        basicSchema.setModifyDate( info.getModificationDate() );
        basicSchema.setCreateDate( info.getCreationDate() );
        basicSchema.setCreatorTool( info.getCreator() );

        metadataStream.importXMPMetadata(xmp.asByteArray());

        InputStream colorProfile = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icm/sRGB Color Space Profile.icm");
        // create output intent

        PDOutputIntent oi = new PDOutputIntent(pdDocument, colorProfile); 
        String value = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1";
        oi.setInfo(value); 
        oi.setOutputCondition(value); 
        oi.setOutputConditionIdentifier(value); 
        oi.setRegistryName("http://www.color.org"); 
        catalog.addOutputIntent(oi);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Now we really need the PDF. Because if PDFBox validates and PDF-Tools doesn't, then it's likely a bug in PDFBox :-( And we also need the code used to generate the PDF.

Comment: Please download it from https://gofile.io/?c=AcWXGW

Comment: This is a bug in PDFBox preflight, I'll fix it soon. https://www.pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/TechNote0010.pdf "An ISO 19005-1 validator shall FAIL otherwise conforming files in which a widget annotation lacks an appearance dictionary." So you should take care that every field has a value thus an appearance stream. Try that and then check again. VeraPDF does not complain about the meta data. I could create an issue there but I'd prefer to have your file with the other problems fixed.

Comment: The missing "about" is somehow related to your usage of the dublin core schema. Please show the code. It wouldn't have happened if you had used `metadata.createAndAddDublinCoreSchema()` because that one sets the "about" thing.

Comment: Re xmp: `xmp.addDublinCoreSchema()` is PDFBox 1.8. You could try calling `dcSchema.setAbout("");`. Re the fields: try calling setValue(something) for each field. This sets the apparance stream, at least in 2.0.16. Not sure about 1.8.

Comment: I just added the code in my initial post. Could you please also post what do I have to add as a PDAppearanceDictionary or PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary or both of them for textfields and comboboxes?

Comment: This should be done automatically when setting the value.

Comment: I removed line pdfaid.setAbout(""); and added line dcSchema.setAbout(""); but still the error occurs with version 2.0.15(is v2.0.16 available?) Also if I do not have comboboxes in the pdf I do not get error (The appearance dictionary doesn't contain an entry).How do I create a combobox correct?I am pretty sure that my comboboxes have a selected value.

Comment: When I create a combobox I get warning message (org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper: widget of field aa has no rectangle, no appearance stream created)

Comment: There is no field "aa". Yes 2.0.16 is available.

Comment: I migrated to version 2.0.16 but still I face both problems. What do you mean there is no field "aa"?

Comment: Your fields all have names like "Fa4dc5963-d229-47b0-80fb-131523f403bd".

Comment: yes............

Comment: Ffc668506-8879-4ce4-9061-bfb564e52175:22:F355f4b2e-8231-4d1e-a461-67a3c78bed31:F582d7219-f416-42c9-a756-7eae74b5a8c1

Comment: I am able to set that field: `acroForm.getField("Ffc668506-8879-4ce4-9061-bfb564e52175:22:F355f4b2e-8231-4d1e-a461-67a3c78bed31:F582d7219-f416-42c9-a756-7eae74b5a8c1").setValue("");` with no log message. Maybe you have several PDFBox versions in your classpath?

Comment: I managed to resolve issue (The appearance dictionary doesn't contain an entry). The problem was that I was setting the value of the combobox before setting the appearance of the widget. Now I set first the appearance of the widget and then the value of the combobox. Now the error that I face with the online validator is "Anonymous RDF resources (rdf:Description without rdf:about attribute) are not allowed in XMP Metadata."

Comment: If I add setAbout("") to all objects then I do not get error "Anonymous RDF resources (rdf:Description without rdf:about attribute) are not allowed in XMP Metadata." and the pdf conforms to the PDF/A-1b standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

1) The failure to report "The appearance dictionary doesn't contain an entry" is a bug in PDFBox preflight that will be fixed in 2.0.17, see [PDFBOX-4586](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4586). According to [this document](https://www.pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/TechNote0010.pdf):

> An ISO 19005-1 validator shall FAIL otherwise conforming files in
>   which a widget annotation lacks an appearance dictionary

2) The "rdf:Description without rdf:about attribute" may or may not be a bug. [VeraPDF](https://verapdf.org) doesn't consider it to be one. Your code used an 1.8.* version. For these, you can call `dcSchema.setAbout("")` to fix this. In 2.0.* the problem doesn't occur if you created the schema with `metadata.createAndAddDublinCoreSchema()`.

I have created an issue in the [VeraPDF project](https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-library/issues/1031) and they *will bring this question for discussion at the next meeting of the Validation technical working group*.

3) That the widgets didn't contain an entry is because at the time `setValue()` was called, not enough information was present (e.g. the rectangle).That is why you got the message `widget of field aa has no rectangle, no appearance stream created`.